# How to get Data from Jason's serializedObject in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api, console-application

I want to return List of Data into Json format.

I am trying various methods for getting data from SerializeObject but I am not able to Deserialize Object and also I try to get data from web API to Console application.
Here is my code of Web API

```
public string Get()
    {
        List<Student> studentList = new List<Student>();
        Random rand = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            int r = rand.Next(1, 1000);
            studentList.Add(new Student
            { 
                ID = i, 
                Name = "Dhruv"+i, 
                Rand = r 
            }); 
        }
        string _JsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(studentList);
        return _JsonData;
    }
```

Here is my Student Class

```
public class Student
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Rand { get; set; }
}
```

Now, i try to get this data into console application.
Here is my code of Console Application.

```
public static void GetJsonData()
    {
        string jsonData = new WebClient().DownloadString("https://localhost:44374/api/GetData");
        List<StudentData> item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<StudentData>>(jsonData);

        foreach (var i in item)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ID: " + i.ID);
            Console.WriteLine("Name: " + i.Name.ToUpper());
            Console.WriteLine("Rand No: "+i.Rand);
        }
    }
```

Here is my StudentData Class

```
class StudentData
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Rand { get; set; }
}
```

Error i am getting is:

> ArgumentException: Could not cast or convert from System.String to
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Data_Collector.StudentData].

This is my Json which i Getting from Web API.

```
"[{\"ID\":0,\"Name\":\"Dhruv0\",\"Rand\":52},{\"ID\":1,\"Name\":\"Dhruv1\",\"Rand\":44},{\"ID\":2,\"Name\":\"Dhruv2\",\"Rand\":118},{\"ID\":3,\"Name\":\"Dhruv3\",\"Rand\":668},{\"ID\":4,\"Name\":\"Dhruv4\",\"Rand\":142},{\"ID\":5,\"Name\":\"Dhruv5\",\"Rand\":864},{\"ID\":6,\"Name\":\"Dhruv6\",\"Rand\":150},{\"ID\":7,\"Name\":\"Dhruv7\",\"Rand\":412},{\"ID\":8,\"Name\":\"Dhruv8\",\"Rand\":515},{\"ID\":9,\"Name\":\"Dhruv9\",\"Rand\":105}]"
```

Comment: What data are you actually receiving in your console app, what errors are you getting?

Comment: and what happens?

Comment: Can you successfully download the json data? Have you tried debugging your code? What is the value of `jsonData`?

Comment: Yes, Data is Successfully Downloaded

Comment: Something which kept my attention when I was reading your code is: You serialize a list of Student. Where on the other hand you are trying to deserialize a List of StudentData. Can you please share your StudentData model ?

Comment: Please include your method definitions.

Comment: Json data doesnt have the data in json format, that includes { }... check your json ... log it and see what it is before you deserialize it

Comment: hmm i feel like if you are adding a student, you would be Using method =POST and not GET , other thing would be to check the JSON message body(syntax).

Comment: I could be wrong but are you sure your localhost is serving https?? Vs http?? **https://localhost:44374/api/GetData**

Comment: It Serving Https

Comment: There isn't anything that can be said as the process you have is correctly written.  Use debugger to see what the value of the json is before deserializin it

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in my comment of your post, you should be using the same class as the deserialized one (even if the same - for the sake of clarity)

To me, your code seems correct. I suspect the json string you try to deserialize to be in the wrong format:
Using your code:

```
string jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(studentList);
List<StudentData> item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<StudentData>>(jsonData);
```

is working fine on my side. Make sure your jsonData is in the format:

```
[
  {"ID":0,"Name":"Dhruv0","Rand":292},
  {"ID":1,"Name":"Dhruv1","Rand":813},
  {"ID":2,"Name":"Dhruv2","Rand":236},
  ... etc ...
]
```

Comment: Incorrect. Deserialization is NOT dependent on which class was used to serialize the string. Any class can be used as long as variable names matvh

Comment: Agreed. But in his case, Student and StudentData is the "same". Keep it tidy and clean as much as possible. It is just best practice to use same class to serialize and deserialize. In my case, I did like him: I serialized List<Student> and deserialized List<StudentData> and this is working - That's why I was suspecting his json string to be in the wrong format

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error it looks like an issue with double serialization. First, your method is serializing the collection to string and the framework is taking care of default serialization(Considering this is rest response).

Identifying the issue:

1. Verify response type of WebClient is 'application/json'
2. Response content string contains an escape character when it should not be there in case of JSON response data.

Solution:

1. Simply modify your method to return collection, no change in client-side.

```
public List<Student> Get()
    {
        List<Student> studentList = new List<Student>();
        Random rand = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            int r = rand.Next(1, 1000);
            studentList.Add(new Student
            { 
                ID = i, 
                Name = "Dhruv"+i, 
                Rand = r 
            }); 
        }
        return studentList;
    }
```

**OR**

2. Deserialize the response content to string first and then to the required collection.

Additionally, if you want to return data from WebAPI it is better to use Request.CreateResponse(StatusCode,Objectdata);

Comment: Yes, I know this way to deserialize a jeson object but I do not want to return the list but I want to return the json

Comment: So if you are aware of the issue (i.e. double serialization) then what is the issue here?

Comment: Do you want to disable serialization of framework itself ?

Answer (score 0):

Following are the three methods I copied

```
        public class Student
        {
            public int ID { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public int Rand { get; set; }
        }

        public class StudentData
        {
            public int ID { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public int Rand { get; set; }
        }
        public static string Get()
        {
            List<Student> studentList = new List<Student>();
            Random rand = new Random();

            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                int r = rand.Next(1, 1000);
                studentList.Add(new Student
                {
                    ID = i,
                    Name = "Dhruv" + i,
                    Rand = r
                });
            }
            string _JsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(studentList);
            return _JsonData;
        }
```

In my main file, i ran the following code which does exactly what you do. Instead of calling an API that you have to get the json, i call the method Get() to get the json. Get gives you a serialized version of the data... then deserialized to another class.

```
    string jsonData = Get();
    //string jsonData = "[{\"ID\":0,\"Name\":\"Dhruv0\",\"Rand\":52},{\"ID\":1,\"Name\":\"Dhruv1\",\"Rand\":44},{\"ID\":2,\"Name\":\"Dhruv2\",\"Rand\":118},{\"ID\":3,\"Name\":\"Dhruv3\",\"Rand\":668},{\"ID\":4,\"Name\":\"Dhruv4\",\"Rand\":142},{\"ID\":5,\"Name\":\"Dhruv5\",\"Rand\":864},{\"ID\":6,\"Name\":\"Dhruv6\",\"Rand\":150},{\"ID\":7,\"Name\":\"Dhruv7\",\"Rand\":412},{\"ID\":8,\"Name\":\"Dhruv8\",\"Rand\":515},{\"ID\":9,\"Name\":\"Dhruv9\",\"Rand\":105}]";
    Console.WriteLine(jsonData);

    List<StudentData> item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<StudentData>>(jsonData);
    foreach(var i in item)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ID: " + i.ID);
        Console.WriteLine("Name: " + i.Name.ToUpper());
        Console.WriteLine("Rand No: " + i.Rand);
    }
```

Both jsonData from Get() method and that string works correctly and gives you the desired output.

```
ID: 0
Name: DHRUV0
Rand No: 52
ID: 1
Name: DHRUV1
Rand No: 44
... // hiding 2 - 7 
ID: 8
Name: DHRUV8
Rand No: 515
ID: 9
Name: DHRUV9
Rand No: 105
```

There is nothing wrong with the code.. Only thing that does not work is your https://localhost call that is supossed to retrieve the json string. Once you fix your API, you'll get the methods working.

Answer (score -1):

// Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();

// Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
 StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

// Read the content. This is the JSON .
                string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

var data = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseFromServer);
                var products = data["Students"].Children();

and then your for loop.

maybe you should try and declare your json object as a var instead of string.

Comment: the author is using type safe data models